# How to run the "screen" command from NSTask?

Tags: unix, arduino, rfid, gnu-screen, nstask

I want to monitor a virtual COM port (Arduino [RFID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification)) on my Mac. I can run "screen /dev/tty.serialnumber" from the terminal, and it outputs the RFID serial number when I swipe it.

As soon as I try it from [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) with an NSTask I get the following output.

> Must be connected to a terminal.

Here's my code:

```
NSTask *cd = [[NSTask alloc] init];

[cd setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/screen"];
[cd setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-L",@"/dev/tty.usbserial-A800509K",nil]];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[cd setStandardOutput: pipe];
[cd setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[cd launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog (@"%@", string);

[cd waitUntilExit];
[cd release];
```

Comment: That’s `screen(1)` telling you that it can only be run from a terminal. Can’t you use another program or read /dev/tty directly? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504714/reading-serial-data-from-c-osx-dev-tty

Answer (score -1):

I think you'd better directly access the COM port, either by using the foundation libraries, or by using third party Obj-C libs (for example, https://github.com/pbosetti/PBSerialPort).
Also, if you want to *monitor* the COM port, you will have to set a thread reading the serial port, and updating a text area in the UI. Remember that secondary thread should update the UI via the method `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector onThread:(NSThread *)thr withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait`.