# If you can use treat serial data as files in C++, what's the purpose of termios?

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, linux-device-driver, tty

I heard you might be able to just do this like so:

```
ostream dev("tty.mydevice");
dev < "hi";
```

So, why do we need termios. In other words, what's the purpose of the code in this question?

[Reading Serial Data From C (OSX /dev/tty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504714/reading-serial-data-from-c-osx-dev-tty)

Comment: Because that's C and this is C++?

Comment: @PCLuddite So they should both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`termios` provides functionality specific to serial ports and terminals which isn't available through standard I/O. For example, it allows for:

- Setting the baud rate
- Reading and writing control lines like RTS/CTS and sending break sequences
- Configuring certain character translation options (local echo, CR/CRLF conversion, support for strange things like teletypes and hardcopy terminals)
- Configuring the effect of control sequences in a terminal (to handle `^C`, `^Z`, etc)
- Getting information about the foreground process in a terminal (job control)
- Getting the window size of a terminal

Comment: So does ostream automatically deduce baud rate?

Comment: @Bob No. If you don't set a baud rate, the port will use a default speed (9600 baud, iirc?) when opened.